# Is there a legitimate way to create custom view for a fullcalendar plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar plugin, which is nice and otherwise fits perfectly for my needs, I have to create a calendar view like this:
[image]

As you can see, every column here is a default dayView column, judging by functionale.
I took a look into fullcalendar sources from github, but still can't see how this can be done, if at all possible.

Comment: I think you'll do better to ask this question to the plugin author.

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa, Adam Shaw DOES NOT want anybody to bother him regarding this plugin. Those uppercase letters are quoted from the plugin site :) He recommends asking here, using 'fullcalendar' tag.
So I did.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it. I must admit this is a very strange behavior in my opinion.

Comment: He may be dealing with some harassment issues.